# Why does one of my Cassandra threads take 100% of my CPU?

Tags: cassandra, jvm, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

One of my Cassandra threads takes 100% of my CPU. I don't know what this thread does and also why it is running at full capacity? Should I give it more ressources or reduce the datasize etc.? You can see this in the thread ID 14809.

I attached my Htop output.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

**Edit:**

I restarted the server so maybe the above thread ID is not the same as the below thread stack but the thread is the same. 
This is my related thread stack:

```
Attaching to process ID 6364, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.102-b14
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 9955: (state = IN_JAVA)
 - java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode() @bci=95, line=1441 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next() @bci=1, line=1461 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.collect.Iterators$3.next() @bci=4, line=163 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.AbstractCollection.contains(java.lang.Object) @bci=40, line=106 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.base.Predicates$InPredicate.apply(java.lang.Object) @bci=5, line=497 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.base.Predicates$NotPredicate.apply(java.lang.Object) @bci=5, line=312 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.base.Predicates$CompositionPredicate.apply(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=536 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext() @bci=27, line=647 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext() @bci=9, line=143 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext() @bci=61, line=138 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext() @bci=4, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(java.util.Collection) @bci=10, line=343 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.HashSet.<init>(java.util.Collection) @bci=10, line=118 (Compiled frame)
 - com.google.common.collect.Sets.newHashSet(java.lang.Iterable) @bci=15, line=218 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.compaction.CFSCompactionStrategy.removeKeys(java.lang.Iterable) @bci=116, line=337 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.compaction.CFSCompactionStrategy.add(org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader, boolean) @bci=81, line=293 (Compiled frame)
 - com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.compaction.CFSCompactionStrategy.handleNotification(org.apache.cassandra.notifications.INotification, java.lang.Object) @bci=18, line=227 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.db.DataTracker.notifyAdded(org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader) @bci=43, line=531 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.db.DataTracker.replaceFlushed(org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable, org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader) @bci=130, line=179 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.replaceFlushed(org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable, org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader) @bci=9, line=234 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.replaceFlushed(org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable, org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader) @bci=6, line=1540 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow() @bci=73, line=336 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run() @bci=1, line=28 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=5, line=297 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run() @bci=163, line=1134 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() @bci=4, line=511 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() @bci=42, line=266 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() @bci=4, line=511 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() @bci=42, line=266 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)
```

Comment: I'd suggest to take a thread dump with `jstack PID >> mydumps.tdump` and start your analysis from there.

Comment: @xmas79 I already attached the thread stack could you take a look? I don't know how to solve this. thanks

Comment: Because it is running code that has been carefully written not to waste resources by often blocking for long periods? What makes you think this is a problem?

Comment: speculation, if it is stuck in this and a few adjacent methods: a not-thread-safe datastructure getting corrupted by concurrent access and forming a cycle internally

Comment: @the8472 what do you mean by that? Probably it's because I have 10.000 cfs blocks. It's really slow now I need it to be quicker.

Comment: I'm saying HashMap is not threadsafe. If you (or cassandra's code) is using it in an unsafe manner it can become corrupted in a manner where its iterator never terminates. But it's just speculation because it would take more than a single thread stack to verify.

Comment: @the8472 ok thanks. So how can i fix this and how can I see what it is doing? thanks

Comment: the same way you fix any other bug. collect information, try a newer version, use a debugger, file issues on bug trackers, etc.